# First time running issues in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I create a phonegap application, but when it runs for first time, it dont works properly. It contains 2 jquery animations that in first run positions gets in some troubles.
I think that its problem is related to cache.

ok. my javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
{
var width=window.innerWidth;
//var id1Width=document.getElementById("Id1").clientWidth;
var myIdWidth=document.getElementById("myId").clientWidth;
width=(width/2)-(myIdWidth/2);
  var height1= window.innerHeight;
   var idHeight= document.getElementById("myId").clientHeight;
  var t=height1;
  t= t-document.getElementById("Id1").clientHeight;
   height1=(height1/2)-(idHeight/2);
     document.getElementById("myId").style.top=height1;
     document.getElementById("myId").style.left=width;
  var s=document.getElementById("Id1").clientHeight;
  //t=height1-2*t;
  //$("button").click(function(){
  //alert("ddccd");
     $("#Id1").animate({top:-height1,height:'0%'},7000);
     $("#Id2").animate({top:(1.02*t-height1-(s)),height:'0%'},7000);
  //})
  }});
```

Comment: Show some code. Show some logcat. Help us to help you. (And don't use PhoneGap, please)

Comment: @OcuS instead of phonegap what would you suggest for someone that knows the front-end languages HTML CSS JS.

Comment: @MatthiasWegtun: Start to learn Java and Android, they are fun ;)

Comment: @vahidkargar: You'll have to explain a bit more what "some troubles" are. It's too vague for now.

Comment: @OcuS in first run, one image go to up properly and other image go to down till hide from screen while it should stop in end of screen as it works in browser.

Comment: @vahidkargar: Please, put this in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: Hi, I also have a small image-related problem when my cordova app is run / page is accessed for the first time. PNGs transparency and position is messed up, until I move on in the app. Then everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of following things(for android)
1. cordova is imported and add to build path.
2. config.xml is properly maintained and configured.
3. Androidmanifst.xml is properly maintained too.
4. The path in the mainactivity.java is proper.

check these things first then see if error is occuring or not.

And as for using phonegap is concerned its the best if used properly and can make a disaster app if not.